# Open a Qt Creator Buffer in Emacs

Tags: qt, emacs

I'm working on a Qt based product suite. I see the advantages of using the blessed IDE, Qt Creator, so I want to include it in my workflow.

There are things I want to do, that I'm used to from emacs, that simple key bindings don't help (macros come to mind).

Is there a way I could spawn an emacs instance with the text of the current document, then transfer the edited results back to Qt Creator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure Emacs as an [External Tool](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-editor-external.html) (**Tools > External > Configure**), and then run it via **Tools > External**.

When saving the file on Emacs, Qt Creator will automatically detect the changes and ask if you want to update the buffer with the new file.

Comment: Thanks @Cássio. Added Emacs under external tools, with 'Executable: emacs' and 'Arguments: %{CurrentDocument:FilePath}'. As a bonus, I was able to record a keybinding to bring up emacs under Keyboard>Tools:External.emacs.